# Drop two elements to split the array to three part evenly in O(n)

Tags: java, algorithm

I encounter a problem to let you drop two elements in an array to make the three part's sum equal.

```
  Ex:
  1 2 4 3 5 2 1
  After I drop the 4 and 5, it becomes 1, 2 | 3 | 2, 1
```

Constraints:

```
  1.Numbers are all integer > 0

  2.Drop two elements in the array, so the three splitted subarrays will have same subarray sum.
```

I have tried it by using two pass algorithm as the following

First pass:O(n)
  Count the accumulated sum from the left so I can get the range sum easily.

Second pass:O(n^2)
  Use nested loop to get the subarray's start and end index. Then, calculate the left, mid, right sum.

```
// 1.get accumulated sum map
int[] sumMap = new int[A.length];
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i ++) {
    sum += A[i];
    sumMap[i] = sum;
}

// 2.try each combination
for(int i = 1; i < A.length - 1; i ++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < A.length - 1; j ++) {
        int left = sumMap[i] - A[i];
        int mid = sumMap[j] - sumMap[i] - A[j];
        int right = sumMap[A.length - 1] - sumMap[j];

        if(left == mid && mid == right)return true;
    }
}
```

Are there any better algorithm that can achieve O(n)?

Thanks

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: The problem description is very vague. You provide an example, but almost no actual mention on the constraints or requirements.

Comment: @jason do you have the latest solution for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that first and last element can't be dropped and all elements are `>0`:

Set a variable `sumleft` to value of first element, `sumright` to value of last element. You also need index variables to remember which elements from left and right were already added to the sums.

1. If `sumleft == sumright`, test if next elements from left and right can be dropped to fulfill requirement. If so -> done. If not take next elements from left and right and add it to the respective sum variable. Back to 1.
2. If `sumleft < sumright`, add next value from the left to `sumleft`. Back to 1.
3. If `sumleft > sumright`, add next value from the right to `sumright`. Back to 1.

If all elements were consumed, there is no solution.

Edit: Testing if requirement is fulfilled when `sumleft == sumright` can be done by initially summing up all elements (also needs only `O(n)`) and checking if this sum minus the elements to drop is equal `sumleft * 3`.

Comment: Did you actually understand his question? Because I didn't. Can you explain to me what the "three parts " he is referring to means? All I understood was that he has an array that is somehow divided into three parts (he doesn't explain how the division happens or based on what).

Comment: @AliElgazar If I understand right, two elements of the array are dropped and the places where they were dropped function then as separators to cut the array into three smaller subarrays (with equal sum of the elements).

Comment: Hats off to you sir, I didn't understand that at all from his post. Well done.

Comment: @MichaelButscher how would we get the third element this way?

Comment: @Danish, what do you mean, which third element?

Comment: If sumleft == sumright, test if next elements from left and right can be dropped to fulfill requirement. If so -> done. I assume by the "requirement" in this phrase you mean that the left off third subarray's sum is equal to the sumleft and sumright?

Comment: Counter example: 1,4,2,3,5,2,1

Comment: @MauricePerry I can't find any solution for your example with or without my algorithm.

Comment: @MichaelButscher same as above: drop the 4 and the 5

Comment: @MauricePerry, the remaining groups "1 ¦ 2 3 ¦ 2 1" have different sums. This isn't a solution.

Comment: @MichaelButscher you're right: it's not a solution. The solution is 1, 2 | 3 | 2, 1

Comment: @MauricePerry, the separators must be placed where the dropped elements were.

Comment: Is this really O(n)? It looks to me that "test if next elements from left and right can be dropped to fulfill requirement" means summing all elements of the central group, an operation that by itself already costs O(n). If the sum doesn't match, one has to go back, move the pointers and try again. This repetition costs an additional O(n), which, multiplied by the "sum central group" operation, results in O(n^2)... unless I am missing something.

Comment: @LucioPaiva This needs only the sum over all elements calculated initially (see my edit of the answer), therefore it is `O(n+n) = O(n)`.

Comment: That edit made a huge difference :-) Nice! Thanks for taking the time to add it.

Answer (score 24):

- **Step 1:** Create a sum array
- **Step 2:** Follow two pointer approach

  ```
    public boolean solution(int[] A) {

    int leftPointer = 1;
    int rightPointer = A.length - 2;
    int leftPartSum, middlePartSum, rightPartSum;
    int[] sumArray = new int[A.length];

    // Initializing the sum array
    sumArray[0] = A[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < A.length; i ++)
        sumArray[i] = sumArray[i-1] +  A[i];

    // Using two Pointer technique
    while(leftPointer < rightPointer) {

        leftPartSum = sumArray[leftPointer] - A[leftPointer];
        middlePartSum = sumArray[rightPointer] - sumArray[leftPointer] - A[rightPointer];
        rightPartSum = sumArray[A.length - 1] - sumArray[rightPointer];

        if(leftPartSum == middlePartSum && middlePartSum == rightPartSum)
            return true;

        if (leftPartSum < rightPartSum)
            leftPointer++;
        else if (leftPartSum > rightPartSum)
            rightPointer--;
        else{                   // Else condition denotes: leftPartSum == rightPartSum
            leftPointer++;
            rightPointer--;
        }
    }
    return false; // If no solution is found then returning false
    }
  ```

**Detailed Explanation:**

**Sum Array:** In the first pass over array, count the accumulated sum from the left  to right. Althought this will take O(n) time to create a sum array but this will help you in getting the leftPartSum, middlePartSum and rightPartSum in O(1) at any given time.

**Two Pointer Approach:** In two pointer approach, One pointer starts from the beginning while the other pointer starts from the end.

[image]

In this case, If we remove the first element or last element, then there is no way in which we can split the array into 3 equal parts. Hence, we can safely assume that

```
int leftPointer = 1; 
int rightPointer = A.length - 2;
```

**Note:**  Array contains indexed from 0 to n-1;

Now, we move the pointer towards each other  and at every movement we calculate leftPartSum, middlePartSum and rightPartSum. Whether we need to move left pointer or right pointer is decided by the fact that which one of the two sums (leftPartSum or rightPartSum is smaller)

Comment: Sorry but what's the purpose to move the pointer toward or forward depending the leftPArt and the rightPart? Can you explain it? Also why we can not take the first and last position instead? you say there's no way to split into 3 equal part, but why?

Comment: Please, I want to understand it, could you give me the explanation please?

Comment: @StuartDTO if you take the first element you are not leaving any element to its left, therefore the most parts you could split the array into would be 2... unless you remove the last element, then you would only have one part of the array: the middle.

For example, if you take the array `[2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 9, 2, 2, 2]`, taking the second and seventh element would leave us with three parts: `[2]`, `[5, 3, 3, 9]` and `[2, 2]`. When you drop an element is the same as if you put an imaginary separator. A separator in the first or last place simply doesn't separe anything.

Comment: without extra space you can use this with the same array just need to calculate the sum, divide the sum by three and each part can't exceed the sum/3 value, left pointer can be increased by one each time and right pointer should be decreased by each pointer. Once the subSum overflows that is the break part. if leftSum == rightSum we just need to check sum for middle between {leftPointer+1 --- rightPointer-1}, if that is also same return true else false. Which will become same to the accepted answer eventually once instead of taking sum we are directly multiplying it by 3

Answer (score 0):

The results below are more a "brute" approach, should work for negative numbers as well. Also a version where we can remove any 2 items and split by any index is added. although it's just a pseudo code.

if the array is split by those items we take out...

```
var count = a.Length (a is input)

// we need:
for i=0; i<cnt; i++
sum += a[i]
sumLeft[i] = a[i]; if (i > 0) sumLeft[i] += sumleft[i-1]
sumRight[cnt-1-i] = a[i]; if (i > 0) sumRight[cnt-1-i] += sumRight[cnt-1+1-i]

// calc:
for i=1; i<cnt; i++;
for j=cnt-2; j>i; j--;
if (sumLeft[i-1] == sumRight[j+1-1] == sum - a[i] - a[j] - sumLeft[i-1] - sumRight[j-1]) return true;

otherwise return false aft cycle
```

if we can take out any 2 items and split in any position:

```
for i=0; i<cnt; i++
for j=i+1; j<cnt; j++
newSum = sum - a[i] - a[j]
if (newSum mod 3 != 0) continue;
if passes check(newSum, i, j, a), return true

return false aft cycle

the check (newSum, dropi, dropj, a):
  thirdSum = newSum / 3

  // summarize from left, until we get the third'sum - if we exceed it, we don't have a result
  leftSum = 0;
  i=0;
  do {
    if (i != dropi && i !- dropj) leftSum += a[i]
    i++;
  } while leftSum < thirdSum
  if (thirdSum != leftSum) return false;

  right = 0;
  i=a.Length-1;
  do {
    if (i != dropi && i !- dropj) rightSum += a[i]
    i++;
  } while rightSum < thirdSum
  if (thirdSum != rightSum) return false;

  return true;
```