# Finding possibility of 2 indexes for list breakdown in 3 lists of equal sums

Tags: python, algorithm, list, performance, load-balancing

I have to write a function that takes integer list (ls) as input and return True or False, based on the condition:

1. If there exist any 2 indexes (ix1,ix2),ignore those elements from list and break down in 3 smaller lists such that if `sum(ls[0:ix1])==sum(ls[(ix1+1):ix2])==sum(ls[ix2+1:])` return True

e.g. `if list=[1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2],`it should return`True,`because for indexes 2,5`-> 1+3==2+2==1+1+2`

I tried writing the below function, but doesn't seem to be efficient:

```
def func(A):
    y=False
    for i in range(len(A)-2):
        for j in range(len(A)-i-3):
          t1=A[0:i]
          t2=A[(i+1):j+i+2]
          t3=A[j+i+3:]
          if sum(t1)==sum(t2)==sum(t3):
              y=True
              break
        if y==True:break

    return y
```

But I can't figure out the best way of doing search for indexes ix1,ix2, except trying out all index combinations

Comment: Can the list include negative numbers?

Comment: no, numbers are >0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop two elements to split the array to three part evenly in O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600864/drop-two-elements-to-split-the-array-to-three-part-evenly-in-on)

Answer (score 0):

I can give an optimization and a approach for a better algo.

You should start by making a sum_list where each element will be equal to the sum of all previous elements, so for the example in the question, sum_list would be `sum_list = [1,4,7,9,11,13,14,15,17]`.

Now instead of calculating sum everytime, you can just take the difference of certain elements in sum_list to find the sum making it an O(1) operation.

A better algorithm would be using two pointers on the sum_list array. They would be initialized as one at the start and one at the end. Then you calculate all the sums, based if one sum if less or greater than the other sum you can move the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52600976/2034787), the trick is to only look at the left and right sums when deciding where to move the pointers.

```py
def f(A):
  s1 = 0
  s2 = A[1]
  s3 = 0

  for i in range(2, len(A) - 1):
    s2 = s2 + A[i]

  pl = 0
  pr = len(A) - 1

  while pl < pr:
    if s1 == s2 and s2 == s3:
      return (True, pl, pr)

    if s1 == s3:
      s1 = s1 + A[pl]
      pl = pl + 1
      s3 = s3 + A[pr]
      pr = pr - 1
      s2 = s2 - (A[pl] + A[pr])
    elif s1 < s3:
      s1 = s1 + A[pl]
      pl = pl + 1
      s2 = s2 - A[pl]
    elif s1 > s3:
      s3 = s3 + A[pr]
      pr = pr - 1
      s2 = s2 - A[pr]

  return False

A = [1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]

print(A)
print(f(A))
```

Comment: do you have it's python equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use accumulate from itertools to compute the running sum of values forward and backward.  If there is a common number between these two lists of sums, then you can check if the sum of elements between their positions matches that common number.

Using a dictionary to check for a match will give you a response in O(n) time.

```
from itertools import accumulate
def can3Part(numbers):
   forward  = list(accumulate(numbers))
   backward = {forward[-1]-sf:i for i,sf in enumerate(forward,1)}
   for i,sf in enumerate(forward[:-4]):
       if sf in backward and sf == forward[backward[sf]-2]-forward[i+1]:
           return True
   return False 

can3Part([1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]) # True
```

If you're not allowed to use library functions, you can replace accumulate() with a loop or a list comprehension:

```
forward = numbers[:1]
for n in numbers[1:]: forward.append(n+forward[-1])

# or (less efficient):

forward  = [ sum(numbers[:i+1]) for i in range(len(numbers)) ]
```